# Android Crashlytics Not Capturing All Crashes

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am using Fabric.io crashlytics for capturing crashes occurring in my app. But it isn't capturing crashes on layout files. Is there anyway to get those crashes as well, or am I doing something wrong? Whenever crashed occurs on layout file, crashlytics is not giving me logs about that.
Or there might be some alternative for achieving the purpose?

Comment: Maybe you had these crashes and you closed them on crashlytics... That could be the problem

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771420/crashlytics-not-showing-crashes-for-release-build-android