# Crashlytics not showing crashes for release build Android

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am facing isssue with Crashlytics. Not sure what I am doing wrong.
I have two buildTypes release and debug as below.
Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.2.0'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apt {
   arguments {
    // you should set your package name here if you are using different application IDs
    resourcePackageName "com.testapp"
   }
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.testapp"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode 55
       versionName "5.2.0"
       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
   }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}

  lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
       maven {
          url 
         "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

dependencies {  
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
      transitive = true;
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have also integrated Answers to capture events. The strange thing is, that no crashes are getting reported in Fabric Dashboard. First I thought it may be issue with the proguard, so I added below lines to make sure, but still no luck. Not sure if I need to do something more for the release build.

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

The release build is capturing and showing me all the data for number of users, events etc., but no crashes.

I had added the debug{ } buildType later, to separate the debug an release build on Fabric dashboard.

I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: How are you initializing the Crashlytics kit in application?

Comment: @Sanoop: I have initialized it in the Application class. like: Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

Comment: It's not working for only release build, right?

Comment: @Sanoop yes, its not working for release. So I added a debug buildType and the debug crashes are getting logged. Only I do not see any crashes from release build

Comment: For just to test things out can add this line to your release build type and check if crash is logging? `ext.enableCrashlytics = true`

Comment: @Sanoop: I did try that as well, doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add this in your Gradle file:
release {
     buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
    }

Comment: @RakshitNawani: I tried with it, still didn't work.

Comment: can you show your full gradle file?

Comment: @RakshitNawani: I have added the gradle file in my question above. Thanks

Comment: Add debuggable(true) and check log? https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Comment: Mike from Fabric here, do you see the debug flavor active in Fabric?

Comment: @MikeBonnell: Thanks for your help. I was able t fix this issue , I have added below the reason it was not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find out why it wasn't working. I missed this point while adding Fabric:

"Make sure the Fabric.with() line is after all other 3rd-party SDKs that set an UncaughtExceptionHandler"

I had few uncaught exception handlers after I had initialised Fabric.
But what I didn't understand is why it worked for debug and not release. If it had to fail, it should have failed for both release and debug as well.

It did fix my issue, but would like to know why that could have happened.

Thanks all for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: my crashlytics is not working with any of release . can you share your code.