# Crashlytics not reporting crash with app bundle but working fine with apk

Tags: android, firebase, apk, bundle, crashlytics

Crashes aren't reported anymore on the crashlytics ( firebase ) console when I upload an app bundle of my app on the Play Store. 
Strange thing :  if I release an apk it works fine.

Do you have any ideas of what can produce this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crashlytics not showing crashes for release build Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771420/crashlytics-not-showing-crashes-for-release-build-android)

Comment: No it didn't.. Only crashlytics get the problem, others firebase features are working fine.